# If I know the coordinates of a right angle triangle how can I find the distance between the centroid and the incircle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have points $A(6,0)$, $B(6,8)$ and $C(0,8)$

Comment: Just compute the coordinates of the centroid, the coordinates of the incenter and the inradius. What is difficult?

Comment: In barycentric coordinates $$G=\frac{A+B+C}{3},\qquad I=\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c}$$ and $r=\frac{2\Delta}{a+b+c}$ for right triangles simplifies into $r=\frac{ab}{a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Comment: In your case the incenter and the centroid have the same abscissa: that makes the problem even easier.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do it without the formula of the incenter

Comment: You have a right triangle with $r=2$, so the incenter lies at $B-(2,2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw $\Delta ABC$.

$AB=8$, $AC=10$ and $BC=6$.

Thus, $r=\frac{6+8-10}{2}=2$ and the incenter $I(6-2,8-2)$ or $I(4,6)$.

In another hand the centroid $M\left(\frac{6+6+0}{3},\frac{0+8+8}{3}\right)$ or $M\left(4,\frac{16}{3}\right)$.

Thus, $IM=6-\frac{16}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: Why is the incenter (6-2, 8-2)?

Comment: @Alexandra  If incircle touches to $BC$ in the point $K$ and touches to $AB$ in the point $M$ then $KBMI$ is square, which says that $BK=BM=2$.